# Webpack: How to export a single class as a UMD library?

Tags: webpack, umd

In my project [semantic-version](https://github.com/pearnaly/semantic-version), I am exporting a UMD bundle with webpack.

When imported with `<script src="bundles/semVersion.js"></script>` in a HTML file, the interesting single class is then available under `SemVersion.SemVersion()` (`<lib name>.<class name>()`). How can I do to have it directly exposed as SimVersion()? (Actually like jQuery for example).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webpack` has [`export`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport) option to export whatever in your library. It can be used in your case where a class as being exported as default.

```js
{
    output: {
        library: {
            name: 'SemVersion',
            type: 'umd',
             // add this to export your class to the library
            export: "default"
        },
    },
}
```